# How to use input field value in LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html

I have below table in lwc, size of the lineItem list is 11 records and accordingly it created 11 input fields now whenever I add anything on one column it shows on all 11 but the the requirement is add different values in all 11 fields and on a click of a button get all different values.

Button:

```
<lightning-button label="Apply %" variant="brand" onclick={applyPercentage}></lightning-button>
```

table:

```
<template if:true={lineItemData}>
              <template for:each={lineItemData} for:item="lineItem">
                <tr key={lineItem.key}>
                  <td>
                    <lightning-input type="checkbox" variant="label-hidden">
                    </lightning-input>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <lightning-input variant="label-hidden"
                      value={lineItem.Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__r.APTS_Storage_Category__c}>
                    </lightning-input>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <lightning-input variant="label-hidden" value={lineItem.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r.Name}>
                    </lightning-input>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <lightning-input variant="label-hidden" type="number" data-key={lineItem.Id} label="percentageValue" onchange={percentageChange}>
                    </lightning-input>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </template>
```

JS:

```
percentageChange(event) {
    this.lineItemData
        .find(item => item.Id === event.currentTarget.dataset.key)
        .percentage = event.target.value;
}

applyPercentage() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lineItemData));
}
    }

@wire(getIlineItemData, { productConfigId: '$productConfigId' })
LineItemData({ data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.lineItemData = data;
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c> getIlineItemData(Id productConfigId) {

    Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c[] uniqueLineItemList = new Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c[0];
    string[] uniqueStringList = new string[0];



    for(Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c lineItem : [SELECT Id,Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r.name, Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__r.APTS_Storage_Category__c, Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r.Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__c
                                                FROM Apttus_Config2__LineItem__c WHERE (Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r.Family='Test'  OR Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r.Family='Storage')
                                                and Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__c =:productConfigId]) {
        if(!uniqueStringList.contains(lineItem.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r.name)) {
            uniqueStringList.add(lineItem.Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r.name);
            uniqueLineItemList.add(lineItem);

        }
    }
    return uniqueLineItemList;
}
```

lineItem console log:

> {"Id":"a4e6E000000Bob9QAC","Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c":"01tw0000005KLpBAAW","Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c":"a4y6E000000NWOGQA4","Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__c":"a516E000000HdtqQAC","Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r":{"Name":"1045-Collagen
>   IV","Id":"01tw0000005KLpBAAW"},"Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__r":{"APTS_Storage_Category__c":"Frozen","Id":"a4y6E000000NWOGQA4"},"Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r":{"Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__c":"a3l6E000000BfKoQAK","Id":"a516E000000HdtqQAC"}},{"Id":"a4e6E000000BobAQAS","Apttus_Config2__ProductId__c":"01tw0000005KKoyAAG","Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__c":"a4y6E000000NWOHQA4","Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__c":"a516E000000HdtqQAC","Apttus_Config2__ProductId__r":{"Name":"10-V-Plex
>   MSD Pro-Inflammatory Panel-RFTS
>   493","Id":"01tw0000005KKoyAAG"},"Apttus_Config2__AttributeValueId__r":{"APTS_Storage_Category__c":"Ambient","Id":"a4y6E000000NWOHQA4"},"Apttus_Config2__ConfigurationId__r":{"Apttus_QPConfig__Proposald__c":"a3l6E000000BfKoQAK","Id":"a516E000000HdtqQAC"}},

I have updated my question as suggested below, but still I don't see the percentage property in the lineitem array, I request you to please look into it one more time.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are not able to get percentage is because the wired `data` is immutable. So, you can get the clone as below after which it should work:

```
if (data) {
    this.lineItemData = [...data];
}
```

I assume data here is the list of records and so using `[...]`

---

1. You do not need `key` on all `td`s .
2. Even if you use ***label-hidden*** variant, you need to put label for ***lightning-input*** .
3. You do not need `value` on the column **percentageValue** as you should collect and modify corresponding row in `lineItemData` .
4. You should use some identifier like `data-key` to know which row is being modified. Then in the change handler you can assign to exactly that row data field .

HTML:

```
<td>
    <lightning-input variant="label-hidden" data-key={lineItem.key} label="percentageValue" type="number" onchange={PercentageChange}>
    </lightning-input>
</td>
```

JS:

```
PercentageChange(event) {
    this.lineItemData
        .find(item => item.key === event.currentTarget.dataset.key)
        .percentage = event.target.value;
}
```

Here is the [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/mmZFXGVOk/2/edit) that I created for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need, it is working perfectly in playground but in real time I am not able to see percentage property in line Item array , you have already done a lot but I request you to please look into it one more time and please suggest what i am missing, I have updated the question thank you so much again.

Comment: instead of returning the list of sobject in apex I even tried creating the wrapper class and created a property name percentage but still not able to get the percentage value from the page, I also tried this.lineItem = {...data} or Object.assign({}, data but still no luck, please suggest.

Comment: It should not be `{...}`, it should be `[...data]`. Added in answer. :)

Comment: Still it doesn't make any difference, I am getting below error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'percentage' throws